# Ec2 instance refusing TCP request on custom port

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, tcp, port, netcat

`nc -vz x.x.x.x 22` gives output succeeded while

`nc -vz x.x.x.x 12346` gives Connection refused

Inbound rule is created for custom TCP at port 12346[image]

Comment: Do you have anything listening on the custom port?

Comment: @Marcin i have 2 instances and i want them to communicate with each other. I have a code which runs as a server on one instance and client on one and these are trying to communicate with each other at Port 12346. This runs when i do so on two devices, but not working when i do this on two instances.

Comment: What do you mean by "on two device" and "on two instances"? What are these devices? I guess they are not instances?

Comment: These two devices are two different PC's on a same network. The client connects to server using port 12346 and the server recieves the packet. I want the same to happen between two EC2 instances

Comment: Are the two instances in same subnet and/or VPC?

Comment: Yes, both are under same security group

Comment: Does it work if you use `nc -vz localhost:12346`?

Comment: Just understood what's happening, the initial interaction between these two devices was via Multicast. This isn't supported on EC2. The TCP connection was made after the successful UDP multicast interaction, which failed and the code never listened to TCP requests at the port 12346.

Thanks anyway.